# Adding a column SQL Lite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-design

I am having trouble adding another column it just bugs after 5 columns..it says in logs that i have only 5 columns...
check this
Logcat

```
11-05 03:31:45.455: I/dalvikvm(3845): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
11-05 03:31:46.395: D/dalvikvm(3845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 78K, 8% free 2671K/2884K, paused 80ms, total 82ms
11-05 03:31:46.405: I/dalvikvm-heap(3845): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.341MB for 635812-byte allocation
11-05 03:31:46.475: D/dalvikvm(3845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 3291K/3508K, paused 67ms, total 67ms
11-05 03:31:46.595: D/Insert:(3845): Inserting ..
11-05 03:31:46.595: D/Reading:(3845): Reading all naps..
11-05 03:31:47.395: D/(3845): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a20c298, tid 3845
11-05 03:32:01.885: D/dalvikvm(3845): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 220K, 9% free 3584K/3936K, paused 78ms, total 91ms
11-05 03:32:30.646: D/dalvikvm(3895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 7% free 2671K/2848K, paused 90ms, total 93ms
11-05 03:32:30.667: I/dalvikvm-heap(3895): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.341MB for 635812-byte allocation
11-05 03:32:30.796: D/dalvikvm(3895): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 3291K/3472K, paused 100ms, total 100ms
11-05 03:32:30.876: D/Insert:(3895): Inserting ..
11-05 03:32:30.876: D/Reading:(3895): Reading all naps..
11-05 03:32:30.976: E/CursorWindow(3895): Failed to read row 0, column 5 from a CursorWindow which has 11 rows, 5 columns.
11-05 03:32:30.986: D/AndroidRuntime(3895): Shutting down VM
11-05 03:32:30.986: W/dalvikvm(3895): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.androidsqlite/com.androidhive.androidsqlite.NapDbase}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.DatabaseHandler.getAllNapChecks(DatabaseHandler.java:110)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at com.androidhive.androidsqlite.NapDbase.onCreate(NapDbase.java:75)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
11-05 03:32:31.016: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):     ... 11 more
```

My Database.

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "NapsManager";

// NapChecks table name
private static final String TABLE_NapS = "Naps";

// NapChecks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_MALL = "mall";
private static final String KEY_LATIT = "latit";
private static final String KEY_LONGIT = "longit";
private static final String KEY_INTER = "inte";
private static final String KEY_CATE = "cate";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_NapS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NapS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_MALL + " TEXT," + KEY_LATIT + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_LONGIT + " TEXT," + KEY_INTER + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CATE + " TEXT" +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_NapS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NapS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new nap
void addNapCheck(NapCheck nap) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, nap.getName()); // NapCheck Name
    values.put(KEY_MALL, nap.getMall()); // NapCheck Phone
    values.put(KEY_LATIT, nap.getLatit()); // NapCheck Name
    values.put(KEY_LONGIT, nap.getLongit());
    values.put(KEY_INTER, nap.getInte());
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_NapS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single nap
NapCheck getNapCheck(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NapS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_MALL, KEY_LATIT, KEY_LONGIT, KEY_INTER, }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    NapCheck nap = new NapCheck(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
    // return nap
    return nap;
}

// Getting All NapChecks
public List<NapCheck> getAllNapChecks() {
    List<NapCheck> NapList = new ArrayList<NapCheck>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NapS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NapCheck nap = new NapCheck();
            nap.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            nap.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            nap.setMall(cursor.getString(2));
            nap.setLatit(cursor.getString(3));
            nap.setLongit(cursor.getString(4));
            nap.setLongit(cursor.getString(5));
            // Adding nap to list
            NapList.add(nap);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return nap list
    return NapList;
}

// Updating single nap
public int updateNapCheck(NapCheck nap) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, nap.getName());
    values.put(KEY_MALL, nap.getMall());
    values.put(KEY_LATIT, nap.getLatit());
    values.put(KEY_LONGIT, nap.getLongit());
    values.put(KEY_INTER, nap.getLongit());
    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_NapS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(nap.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single nap
public void deleteNapCheck(NapCheck nap) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NapS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(nap.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting Naps Count
public int getNapChecksCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NapS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

}
```

And this is my Getters and Setters

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

public class NapCheck {

//private variables
int _id;
String _name;
String _mall;
String latit;
String longit;
String inte;
String cate;
// Empty constructor
public NapCheck(){

}
// constructor
public NapCheck(int id, String name, String _mall,String latit, String longit, String inte){
    this._id = id;
    this._name = name;
    this._mall = _mall;
    this.latit = latit;
    this.longit = longit;
    this.inte = inte;
}

// constructor
public NapCheck(String name, String _mall,String latit, String longit, String inte){
    this._name = name;
    this._mall = _mall;
    this.latit = latit;
    this.longit = longit;
    this.inte = inte;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this._name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this._name = name;
}

// getting phone number
public String getMall(){
    return this._mall;
}

// setting phone number
public void setMall(String phone_number){
    this._mall = phone_number;
}


public String getLatit(){
    return this.latit;
}

// setting phone number
public void setLatit(String latit){
    this.latit = latit;
}


public String getLongit(){
    return this.longit;
}

// setting phone number
public void setLongit(String longit){
    this.longit = longit;
}

public String getInte(){
    return this.inte;
}

public void setInte(String inte){
    this.inte = inte;
}

public String getCate(){
    return this.cate;
}

// setting phone number
public void setCate(String cate){
    this.cate = cate;
}
}
```

I don't know what is wrong everytime i set a column in public List getAllNapChecks() it gets bugged and says i only have five columns i don't know i've been doing this for hours..Thanks in advance..Just tell if you need more

```
public List<NapCheck> getAllNapChecks() {
    List<NapCheck> NapList = new ArrayList<NapCheck>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NapS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            NapCheck nap = new NapCheck();
            nap.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            nap.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            nap.setMall(cursor.getString(2));
            nap.setLatit(cursor.getString(3));
            nap.setLongit(cursor.getString(4));
```

this line is where i get problem most of the time..

```
            nap.setLongit(cursor.getString(5));

            // Adding nap to list
            NapList.add(nap);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return nap list
    return NapList;
}
```

Comment: Although probably not the cause of your problem, you should close the cursor in getAllNapChecks before the return statement. Even if it returns no rows, it still should be closed when finished with.

Comment: Also, are you certain your table really has more than 5 columns? Did you perhaps add columns to the definition after first creating it but forgot to increase the database version? You could increment your DATABASE_VERSION to trigger onUpgrade and get a brand new version of the table. Or pull the database file from the device using DDMS and examine it in something like SQLite studio to confirm it does look like you think it does?

Comment: That is the question. how can i be certain that i have more than 5 columns because as it says in logcat that i only have 5 columns..as you can see in the oncreate i have created a table with 7 columns..and it runs execsql fine..where do you set the number of columns aside from create table?

Comment: See Erastus's answer - he's saying the same thing. I can see that your table is defined with 7 columns but was that the case when you first created it? If not, you need to trigger onUpgrade to get it rebuilt. Regardless, I would do this anyway, to be certain that the table is defined correctly. Alternatively you could create a new AVD and do a fresh install there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this isn't your first DB-schema, that you created.

You have to increase your DB-version, if you edit your DB-schema. Otherwise neither onUpdate() will not be called.

Try:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Comment: Ok it worked..so that is why but to be honest this is the second time i edited the schema..so i dont know why it worked in my first edit but thanks for the solution..

Answer (score 0):

I think the unwanted space and comma after the KEY_INTER(last field) is the problem change that.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NapS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
        KEY_NAME, KEY_MALL, KEY_LATIT, KEY_LONGIT, KEY_INTER}, KEY_ID + "=?",
        new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I already did. It still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The [onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) method in DatabaseHandler is called only once when the database is accessed for the first time. This means that any changes to the schema will not result in this method being called.

To apply the change in schema, you can take either of two actions:

1. Uninstall and then install the application in the device/emulator.
2. Increase the value of **DATABASE_VERSION** in order to trigger a call to [onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29). As per your implementation, this will result in the existing table being dropped and recreated.

Comment: Depending on where the database is stored unintalling won't work. Implementing `onUpgrade() should be considered the best approach, since the database`-scheme is likely to change in some future versions of your app and so you probably have to implement it anyway. It is also possible to execute `ALTER TABLE` statements in `onUpgrade()` so it is not neccessary to drop and recreate the table (although it is the simpliest way).